# AngularJS and ngStorage to remember settings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to deliver some data to a table. Above the table is a series of checkboxes which show/hide columns in the table.

How can I persist a user's checkbox preferences when they leave/refresh the page?

I've done some reading and I think I may be able to use [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) to do this?

Here's a basic outline of my code:

```
<input id="goals" type="checkbox" ng-model="checked.goals"><label for="goals">Goals</label>

<table ng-cloak>
    <thead>
        <td ng-show="checked.goals">Goals</td>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="stat in stats">
        <td ng-show="checked.goals">@{{ stat.goals }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm reading through the ngStorage/AngularJS docs as I'm still new to the framework, but I thought someone else may have encountered the same challenge.

Comment: `ngStorage` is very simple to use and ideal for what you want

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ngStorage before, but I was able to store user prefs similar to this situation by simply using localStorage. I created a storage object and the keys mapped to the names of the checkboxes. When the controller loads, I read the object from localStorage and set the values accordingly.

Comment: Great. I'll do some research on local storage this evening and try to wrap my head around it.